# Which date formats can the dateparser module recognize?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to make a list of equivalent date strings from an initial datestring, each having a different format.

```
def generate_string_list(datestr):
   # todo: return list of equivalent datestr using all known formats

>> generate_string_list("23/05/1992")
["23/05/1992", "23-05-1992", "23rd of May 1992", ...]
```

I'm thinking of doing this by converting `datestr`to a `datetime.date` object, then using `datetime.strftime` with a list of formats to generate the list of date strings.

**The question:** I can come up with a bunch of known date formats off the top of my head, but I'd like to get a more comprehensive list. I tried looking at the [`dateparser` module](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) source, but I haven't been able to find the list of formats it uses in its parsing.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of different date formats, if you include strings like `"23rd of May 1992"`...

Comment: Why would one do this?

Comment: I don't believe one exists. And perhaps it wouldn't be entirely possible to build one either since it might correctly recognise one format for only half the year. I love the library to get something working quickly but when I profiled it with line_parser once, I saw just how much overhead there was involved. So, it might be tough to even try build this list yourself from the codebase since I guess it will have a lot of combinations.

Comment: I fear, any combination of month, day and year with any delimiter `/-., ` was used somewhere. `06/04/09`